# How to install koalas with conda?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda, spark-koalas

According to the [koalas docs](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install.html), installing koalas with conda should be as easy as

```
conda install koalas
```

But this raises the error:

> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment:
>   failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current channels:
>
> - koalas
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/win-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
>   you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I tried running

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyspark
```

first too, and that seemd to work out just fine. But `koalas` still raises the same error. Is there something more to

> Koalas requires PySpark so please make sure your PySpark is available.

than `conda install -c conda-forge pyspark` that is too obvious to include in the docs?

I've also tried the whole thing in a virtual environment with

```
conda create --name koalas-dev-env
```

if that should matter.

**System info:**

```
Python 3.7.0
Anaconda 2019.10
```

Comment: Have you tried `conda install -c conda-forge koalas`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller No, I had not. And yes, it worked. And yes, of course I should have tried it. To my defense, this was ***not*** suggested on [koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install.html)

Comment: @FlyingTeller In my defence, when adding the answer your comment wasn't there. Yeah, that's the thing. And yeah, I guess it would make sense to make a PR to docs to make sure people can install the package. I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

`conda create -c conda-forge -n koalas-dev-env koalas pyspark`

will do. You run into issue since you have not provided the `conda-forge` channel. The latter you can also add to the `.condarc` config file.

[EDIT]

As pointed out by the OP, this should have been made clear in the docs. I made a [pull request](https://github.com/databricks/koalas/pull/1288) to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm still wondering why this is not clearly specified in the docs though.

Comment: You're right, I guess that's because so many developers adds `conda-forge` to channels that they forget about that when writing docs. I will submit a pull request with the change.